# How to match parameters with dots in Rails 4 constraints?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

This sound simple. What I'm trying to do is a segment constraint using a separate class to allow parameters with **multiple** dots.

This works fine:

```
# /config/routes.rb
get '/photos/:id', to: 'photos#show', constraints: { id: /[A-Z]+[0-9\.]+/ }
```

And I'm trying to put the constraint inside a class.

```
# /config/routes.rb
get '/photos/:id', to: 'photos#show', constraints: PhotosConstraint.new
```

And this constraint class:

```
# /lib/photos_constraint.rb
class PhotosConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    request[:id] =~ /[A-Z]+[0-9\.]+/
  end
end
```

When I try to access the route, it returns a routing error.

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/photos/id_with_._dot_and_._dot")
```

Comment: tried adding a i after the [A-Z]+[0-9\.]/ ?

Comment: @argentum47 Thanks. It works fine if I have single dot in the `id`, but when I try to have multiple dots, it cannot route correctly. I updated my question.

Comment: thats cool, you need to know about regex. + or * signes are generally used for that (repetitions) but you need to learn.

Comment: @argentum47, That's cool. The only difference is when you put the Regex in the routes, it **works**, but if you put it inside a class it *doesn't*.

Comment: how is that possible.. try to debug it. either by pry or by 'p' ing the variables and checking the values.

Comment: @Ben did you ever solve this?

Comment: @treehau5. Unfortunately, no. We're stuck with constraints in the routes rather than putting it in a class.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```html
# /config/routes.rb 
get '/photos/:id', to: 'photos#show', id: /[A-Z]+[0-9\.]+/, constraints: PhotosConstraint.new
```

Comment: This will work, but I need to remove the Regex inside the route and put it inside the class.